# Looping through a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a blog and on the index I'm looping through a partial for each article so I can show the post without a comments section, it looks like this:

```
<% render partial: 'view_post_only', collection: @articles %>
```

Which takes you to the partial _view_post_only:

```
<h1><%= link_to @article.title, article_path %></h1>
<p>
  Written by <%= link_to @article.author.username, author_path(@article.author_id), class: "article-listing" %>
</p>
<% if @article.image.exists? %>
  <p><%= image_tag @article.image.url %></p>
<% end %>
<p class="article-body"><%= @article.body %></p>
```

I'm getting this error on the first line of view_post_only:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

and lastly, included in my routes.db is:

```
resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your first error, change:

```
<h1><%= link_to @article.title, article_path %></h1>
```

To:

```
<h1><%= link_to @article.title, article_path(@article) %></h1>
```

The `article_path` helper needs an instance of the resource you're attempting to link to so it knows where to go.

Also, the instance of each of your "articles" is not saved in the `@article` variable. By convention rails will singularize the partial's name and give you a method to access the item. In this case that convention would yield a method called `view_post_only` (I think). So you could replace `@article` with `view_post_only` in your template. Like so:

```
<h1><%= link_to view_post_only.title, article_path(view_post_only) %></h1>
```

This convention doesn't seem to work well in this case. To make your partial read better I'd be explicit about what you want to call the item:

```
<% render partial: 'view_post_only', collection: @articles, as: :article %>
```

and then replace your references to `@article` with just `article` in `_view_post_only`.